# What is the mount point for Windows share on Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: ubuntu

I am new to Ubuntu so please be gentle! I am taking the plunge from Windows!! I connected to a Windows share (using Connect to Server... menu) and I can access it on Gnome just fine.

However, I don't know how I can access it in console, or in any other program that requires the path, when it's already connected on Gnome.
What's the mount point for that?  I tried the mount command but it does not show up.

Answer (score 6):

What version of Ubuntu/Gnome?

Newer Gnome uses [gvfs](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/stable/GVfs.html) (from Gtk+'s new [gio](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gio/stable/)) for network shares and similar.  This is a virtual filesystem which does not exist anywhere on the real filesystem -- unless you install the package [gvfs-fuse](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gvfs-fuse), which creates a `~/.gvfs` directory mirroring all your gvfs mounts.  You can use `gvfs-mount -l` to see your gvfs mounts, if you have [gvfs-bin](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gvfs-bin) installed.

Older Gnome uses [gnome-vfs](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gnome-vfs-2.0/stable/), which did not have any convenient way to integrate with the real filesystem.

You can, of course, follow the [MountWindowsSharesPermanently](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) tutorial to mount the network share somewhere on the real filesystem instead of in Gtk+/Gnome's virtual filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

I'm almost sure that gvfs is installed by default in 9.10. The mount point is created in ~/.gvfs (this is /home/your username/.gvfs) after accesing the share with nautilus. It doesn't persist after rebooting the system.